# Getting JAX-RS java.lang.NullPointerException when changes in file

Tags: java, eclipse, jax-rs

Every time i change a code line in my java project in eclipse i get the error:

```
Failed to build or refresh the JAX-RS metamodel while processing a change in the Java Model
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I don't use JAX-RS in my java project! I disabled JAX-RS validator in my preferences but the error is still there!

My eclipse version is:

Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1)

Build id: 20140925-1800

Any ideas why?

Comment: Been experiencing the same thing with Jboss Developer Studio

Comment: I'm using Jboss Developer Studio too...

Answer (score 11):

right click on your project > Properties > JAX-RS and disable JAX-RS support.

hf

Answer (score 1):

For me disabling JAX-RS in project properties wasn't enough. Uninstalling JAX-RS solved the problem though. Go to Help > About Eclipse, click Installation Details, find JAX-RS and uninstall. No side-effects so far.