# Eclipse - Stuck "processing jax-rs changes"

Tags: java, eclipse, jax-rs

I have installed **Eclipse Mars2** and when I try to save changes I got a message saying "*Processing JAX-RS changes... (Waiting)*" and Eclipse freezes for a couple of minutes. I'm developing a **spring-mvc** maven based application using jboss as server (I don't know whether this is relevant or not).

In this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27519957/getting-jax-rs-java-lang-nullpointerexception-when-changes-in-file) a nullPointer is gotten, but I can't see any errors whatsoever. I can't find the "*jax-rs- support*" option in my project either.

Any clues?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Any particular additional plugins you have installed?

Comment: Aside from the default ones of the JavaEE, subversion, jboss red hat and checkstyle.

Comment: If you open the project properties you should be able to see which builders and projects facets are active. Which facets are active?

Comment: There's a "JAX-RS builder" checked. Should I uncheck this one? As fas as I know we are not using JAX-RS in this project.

Comment: Do you even need to ask? ;) This probably came from the project creation wizard you used which setup JavaEE basics; nowadays it is pretty common to use JAX-RS when you do a JavaEE project after all. But that still wouldn't explain why eclipse freezes for so long of course, that sounds a little buggy.

Comment: Yup, I shouldn't have asked such an obvious question XDD. I think it's working!! Thank you very much!! Post your answer please, and I'll mark it as solved. And I completely agree with you, sounds weird to me as well. Thank you again for you help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason for this problem to exist is unclear. A quick Google for the problem doesn't seem to bring up any existing bug report.

Meanwhile, whatever processing features Eclipse has for JAX-RS are quite superfluous and you can easily do without - especially if you do not actually use JAX-RS in your project. So in this case disabling the builder which you will find in the Project properties does the trick to make the problem go away.

Comment: Which is the stable version of eclipse which does not have this issue?

Comment: The latest stable version of Eclipse. There is no proof that this is an actual bug in Eclipse, the only thing documented here is a workaround.

Comment: Still annoying and not very reasonable without any JAX-RS in the project. Eclipse ist losing ground...

Answer (score 0):

You can uncheck JAX-RS from project->properties->project facets . This helped me